# Install ros_lib into the Arduino Environment

Tags: ros, ros-lib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
When i run it in termial `rosrun rosserial_arduino make_libraries.py .`
it will occur:

```
** Warning, failed to generate libraries for the following packages: ***
    object_recognition_capture (missing dependency: xdot)
    pr2_description (missing dependency: convex_decomposition)
    moveit_core (missing dependency: moveit_resources)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aicrobo/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_arduino/src/rosserial_arduino/make_libraries.py", line 91, in <module>
    rosserial_generate(rospack, path+"/ros_lib", ROS_TO_EMBEDDED_TYPES)
  File "/home/aicrobo/catkin_ws/src/rosserial/rosserial_client/src/rosserial_client/make_library.py", line 588, in rosserial_generate
    raise Exception("Failed to generate libraries for: " + str(failed))
Exception: Failed to generate libraries for: ['object_recognition_capture (missing dependency: xdot)', 'pr2_description (missing dependency: convex_decomposition)', 'moveit_core (missing dependency: moveit_resources)']
```

Ubuntu:14.04

Why?Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239649/install-ros_lib-into-the-arduino-environment/) by [Tianyun Xiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/27190/tianyun-xiong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error message says that the `xdot`, `convex_decomposition` and `moveit_resources` packages are missing. I suspect there are other packages that are missing too.

Since you're using ROS on Ubuntu, you can install all of the dependencies that are required by your workspace by using rosdep:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws
rosdep install --from-paths src -i
```

This should install xdot, convex_decomposition and moveit_resources via apt-get.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tianyun Xiong](https://answers.ros.org/users/27190/tianyun-xiong/) on 2016-07-16**:
Thank you very much.I got it